# Splash screen on a Android WebView while loads first time until javascript onload fires

Tags: javascript, android

The desired behavior when opening an app is:

- Show splash screen and load URL in parallel
- When a javascript interface fired when onload just remove the splash screen

`Mainactivity.java`

```
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new JavaScriptInterface(this, cookieManager),"Android");
```

`JavaScriptInterface.java`

```
@JavascriptInterface
  public void hideOrRemoveSplashScreen() {
  objetcSplashScreen.doRemoveSplashScreen();    
  //...
}
```

HTML page (only for pages loaded with app, should detect with User Agent)

```
$(function() {
  try{Android.hideOrRemoveSplashScreen()}catch(e){};
});
```

Activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullfresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/msw_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></WebView>
</androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

I don't know how to load in parallel a simple .png as splash screen with the rest of the app, and then, how to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems this is working, not sure is the right way:

1. Modify activity_main.xml in order to put a container with the image and webview

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/pullfresh"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
      <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/splashimg"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/darkblue"
        android:src="@drawable/splash" />
      <WebView
        android:id="@+id/msw_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"></WebView>
       </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Then add objects in MainActivity.java

```
container = findViewById(R.id.container);
splash = findViewById(R.id.splashimg);
```

And finaly remove image onload inside Oncreate

```
myWebView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChrome() {
[...]
    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int newProgress) {
       if (newProgress == 100){
          container.removeView(splash);
       }
       super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress);
    }
}
```

On load first page fires the removeView and some white body flashes until page is fully loaded, but can be fixed setting `<body style='background-color'>`